# Unit Testing both sides of operation?

Tags: unit-testing

I'm just getting going with unit testing.  Suppose I have a filter class to filter out boxes.  `Box` and `BoxFilter` are defined like:

```
class Box
{
    double GetHeight()
    double GetWidth()
    double GetWeight()
}

class BoxFilter
{
    void SetMaxHeight()
    void SetMaxWidth()
    void SetMaxWeight()
    bool PassesFilter(Box box)
}
```

So if a box does not cross the various max thresholds, then it passes the filter.

My question is about writing unit tests for the `BoxFilter` class's `PassesFilter` method.
I could create the `BoxFilter` in a `SetUp()` method and keep the BoxFilter settings constant and
then manipulate the `Box` properties in each test to verify that it passes or fails.  For example,
set the max height, width, and weight to be 10 and then tweak the box properties to above or below
10 and assert the expected outcomes.

Or, I could keep the `Box` settings constant and 
manipulate the `BoxFilter` settings.

Or alternatively, I could test both scenarios: `BoxFilter` constant
and changing `Box`, and `Box` constant and chaning `BoxFilter`.

Which is the correct way to unit test this
method?  Also would I want to test a range of values, not just say 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind unit testing is to cover both the code and the use cases.  In general, you'd want to do this as simply and as completely as possible, in whatever way seems the most reasonable.

My (personal) preference would be to set up several `BoxFilter`s with varying parameters to test filters with positive, zero, and negative parameters.  For each `BoxFilter`, I'd test several different `Box`es, also with positive, zero, and negative parameters, to be sure you've caught all of the invalid and edge cases.  Then I'd create (at least) one `BoxFilter` with "normal" parameters and test various `Box`es to be sure the correct ones pass the filter.

Kudos for thinking about unit testing early!  I think you'll find that it makes development faster, easier, and just more pleasant.

Comment: Actually that brings up a question in my mind, if you pass SetMaxWeight a negative weight, this is an invalid state to me.  Would you throw an exception if SetMaxWeight is called with less than 0 weight?

Comment: That depends on whether you consider it to be a programming error or a user error.  In general, exceptions catch programming errors that should never occur.  You'll usually check and sanitize all user input, and generate a "friendly" error message if it's invalid.  If you do that, and you decide that `SetMaxWeight` should never be called with invalid input, then it's fine to throw an exception.

Comment: Since not all the tests use the same BoxFilter, I guess rather than use a setup method, you'd use helper methods to create the box filters?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's just a matter of preference, because the way you change the values doesn't actually affect the logic you're testing. Every time you call `PassesFilter()`, only the *current* values of the box and the filter matter - how the values have changed in relation to the surrounding tests doesn't matter. If, on the other hand, you were testing code that actually deals with how sizes change over time, you should test both ways.

The most important thing is that you test corner cases - but whether you do this by testing a fixed filter of e.g. 8.0 vs. a box size of 7.99999, 8.0 and 8.00001 or the other way around shouldn't matter (personally, though, I'd go for a fixed filter and a varying box, since the common use case would presumably be to create a filter and then pass many boxes through it).

Comment: I like the reasoning behind having a fixed filter and testing many boxes because, you're right, that is the more common use case.